# Kotlin Anonymous Inner Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code snippets
Please help me figure out the difference between the same

**Snippet 1**

```
    navbar.setOnItemSelectedListener { id ->
        var fragment: Fragment? = null
        when (id) {
            R.id.home -> fragment = HomeFragment()
            R.id.graphical_stats -> fragment = GraphicalStats()
            R.id.sources -> fragment = SourcesFragment()
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_frame, fragment)
                .commit()
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error Creating Fragment")
        }
    }
```

**Snippet 2**

```
navbar.setOnItemSelectedListener { object : ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(id: Int) {
            var fragment: Fragment? = null
            when (id) {
                R.id.home -> fragment = HomeFragment()
                R.id.graphical_stats -> fragment = GraphicalStats()
                R.id.sources -> fragment = SourcesFragment()
            }
            if (fragment != null) {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_frame, fragment)
                    .commit()
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error Creating Fragment")
            }
        }
```

I am using [ChipNavigationBar](https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar) and have three fragments namely Home Graphical Stats and Sources which will be created or swapped accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality wise, both the snippets are the same.

Snippet 1 is using a lambda expression for setOnItemSelectedListener whereas the Snippet 2 uses a singleton object implementing the interface ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener.

To simply your code, you should use a lambda expression.
Also, you can use lambda expression only if your interface has only 1 function that's need to overridden.

Comment: Actually I tried the second one but it doesn't seem to work 
Only the first one worked
any idea why?

Comment: Because you have added { before setOnItemSelectedListener it should be a normal bracket ( . it should be like this :
`navbar.setOnItemSelectedListener( object : ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onItemSelected(id: Int) {
           //your code 
        })`